# Mapping in mule - convert one element to multiple

Tags: mule

I have an XML input,

```
        <MilitaryHistory>
            <Branch>AString</Branch>
            <Branch>BString</Branch>
        </MilitaryHistory>
```

And it should be converted to

```
        <MilitaryHistory>
            <military>
                <Branch>AString</Branch>
            </military>
            <military>
               <Branch>BString</Branch>
            </military>
        </MilitaryHistory>
```

I don't see any option to map these, when I do the normal mapping from parent level. Target is disabled for `military` element.

I dragged from source `military` to `military` in the target and changed the below in script.

```
output.__id = input.__id;
output.__parent_id = input.__parent_id;
```

to

```
output.__id = input.__id;
output.__parent_id = input.__id;
```

I get below output,

```
         <MilitaryHistory>
            <military>
                <Branch>AString,Bstring</Branch>
            </military>
        </MilitaryHistory>
```

I tried creating rule under `MilitaryHistory` tag, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XSLT to get the expected output... use XSLT Transformer of Mule and use XSLT script in it to get your expected output

Comment: I am already using XSD for this. Above is just one piece of element from lengthy xsd.

Comment: I am not asking about XSD ... I was talking avout XSLT

Comment: I understand, I already have a mule datamapper with JSON input and XML (XSD schema) target. I can not use XSLT in between